# Do page fault, page replacement, and paging happen to the kernel or just to processes, and to the kernel space or the user space?

Tags: linux, virtual-memory

Do page fault, page replacement, and paging happen to

- the kernel or processes, and
- the kernel space or the user space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paging happens only to user space memory from processes. Kernel memory space is always mapped to physical memory and never paged out.

Comment: Thanks. If interested https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/475676/does-the-linux-kernel-have-its-own-page-table